# Is there an ALL(String, List) function to find and return all values in the list containing the String in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, math, eval

I am trying to apply an expression to a DataFrame column which uses an `ALL(String*)` function to find all Strings separated by comma and do some other mathematical operation such as `mean()`.

So I have a dictionary with `key = expression name` and `value = expression` as such:

```
param_exp = {'AVG.P99' : '@df.mean(ALL(P99.*))', ...}
```

df_filtered.columns = ['P99.1', 'P99.2', 'P99.3',...]

Finally I want to return param_exp = {'AVG.P99': '@df.mean(P99.1,P99.2,P99.3,...)), ...}

Here is what I have so far:

```
for key, value in param_exp.items():
    list = []
    string = ""
    for column in df_filtered:
        if "ALL" in str(value):
            search_parm = param_exp[key].split("ALL(")[1]
            search_parm = search_parm.split("*")[0]
            # print(search_parm)
            if search_parm in column.split(search_parm)[0]:
                list.append(column)
    string = ",".join(list)
    string = param_exp[key].split("ALL(")[0] + str(string) + param_exp[key].split("*")[1]
    string = string.strip("ALL").strip("*")
    try:
        param_exp[key] = string
    except:
        pass
print(param_exp)
```

This has not been working out and gives an index error:

```
    string = param_exp[key].split("ALL(")[0] + str(string) + param_exp[key].split("*")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Just wondering if there is an easier way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. Better create minimal working code with example data in code and show expected result for example data.

Comment: maybe string doesn't have `*` and then you can't get `[1]` - you should first use print to see what you have in variables before line which makes problem.

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: instead of `aram_exp[key]` you can use `value`. You could first calculate `search_parm` and later run `for column in df_filtered:` because inside `for column in df_filtered:` you always create the same `search_parm` - so you could do it only once instead of repeate it again and again.

Comment: you do `'P99.1'.split("P99.")` which gives `["", "1"]` so you try to check `if "P99." in ["", "1]`. You should rather check `if "P99." in "P99.1"` without `split("P99.")`

Comment: you could use module `fnmatch` and `fnmatch.filter(df_filtered, 'P99.*')` to get elements which match `P99.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have string which doesn't have `*` so `split("*")` may get only one string but you use `[1]` to get second string.

So you may need

```
if "ALL(" in value and "*)" in value:
```

---

May version with other changes:

- `list` is reserved word to create list so I use variable `selected`
- I use `value` instead of `param_exp[key]`
- during split I keep value which is before `ALL(` and after `*)` so I don't have to split it again to creat `string`

```
df_filtered = ['P99.1', 'P99.2', 'P99.3', 'P11.1', 'P11.2', 'P11.3']
param_exp = {'AVG.P99' : '@df.mean(ALL(P99.*))'}

for key, value in param_exp.items():

    if "ALL(" in value and "*)" in value:
        before, rest = value.split("ALL(")
        search_parm, after = rest.split("*)")
    
        print('search_parm:', search_parm)

        selected = []
        for column in df_filtered:
            if search_parm in column:
                selected.append(column)

        print('selected:', selected)
        
        string = ",".join(selected)
        string = before + string + after
        param_exp[key] = string
    
print('param_exp:', param_exp)
```

Result:

```
search_parm: P99.
selected: ['P99.1', 'P99.2', 'P99.3']
param_exp: {'AVG.P99': '@df.mean(P99.1,P99.2,P99.3)'}
```

---

Maybe it could be better to use module `fnmatch` which can use `*` (any string, even empty) and `?` (exactly one char, not empty) to search matching strings and then you could use i.e `P?9.*` or `*.1`. It is used by module `glob` to search filenames.

```
import fnmatch

df_filtered = ['P99.1', 'P99.2', 'P99.3', 'P11.1', 'P11.2', 'P11.3', 'P1.1']
param_exp = {
    'AVG.P99' : '@df.mean(ALL(P99.*))',
    'AVG.P??.1' : '@df.mean(ALL(P??.1))',
    'AVG.P*.1' : '@df.mean(ALL(P*.1))',
}

for key, value in param_exp.items():

    if "ALL(" in value and ")" in value:
        before, rest = value.split("ALL(", 1)
        search_parm, after = rest.split(")", 1)
    
        print('search_parm:', search_parm)

        selected = fnmatch.filter(df_filtered, search_parm)
        
        print('selected:', selected)
        
        string = ",".join(selected)
        string = before + string + after
        param_exp[key] = string
    
print('param_exp:', param_exp)
```

Result:

```
search_parm: P99.*
selected: ['P99.1', 'P99.2', 'P99.3']

search_parm: P??.1
selected: ['P99.1', 'P11.1']

search_parm: P*.1
selected: ['P99.1', 'P11.1', 'P1.1']

param_exp: {'AVG.P99': '@df.mean(P99.1,P99.2,P99.3)', 'AVG.P??.1': '@df.mean(P99.1,P11.1)', 'AVG.P*.1': '@df.mean(P99.1,P11.1,P1.1)'}
```

---

**EDIT:**

It can be even simpler if you use `f-string` and put `{ALL("P99.*"")}` - so it will try to run function `ALL()` which you have to define.

But `f-string` is executed automatically and it can't use string from user input or from file/database

```
import fnmatch

def ALL(pattern):
    print('pattern:', pattern)
    selected = fnmatch.filter(df_filtered, pattern)
    print('selected:', selected)
    return ",".join(selected)
        
df_filtered = ['P99.1', 'P99.2', 'P99.3', 'P11.1', 'P11.2', 'P11.3']
param_exp = {'AVG.P99' : f'@df.mean({ALL("P99.*")})'}
    
print('param_exp:', param_exp)
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and your through reply. I used the fnmatch for this problem as it was pretty straight forward and I got the resulting expression I was looking for!